# Unable to delete the Azure Subnet that is associated with PowerPlatform Data Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a Subnet in Azure that is associated with PowerPlatform Data Gateway

[image]

I am unable to delete the subnet

> Failed to delete subnet 'np-dat-powerplatform-subnet'. Error: Subnet
> np-dat-powerplatform-subnet is in use by
> ipz12-dat-np-connections-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/np-dat-hub-vnet/subnets/np-dat-powerplatform-subnet/serviceAssociationLinks/PowerPlatformSAL'>np-dat-hub-vnet/np-dat-powerplatform-subnet/PowerPlatformSAL
> and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the
> resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the subnet is delegated to an Azure Service. From the screenshot above I can see that you subnet `np-dat-powerplatform-subnet` has a delegation. In order to delete the subnet, you need to remove this delegation first. You can follow the [steps mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-subnet-delegation#remove-subnet-delegation-from-an-azure-service) here to remove the subnet delegation. If you are unable to remove the delegation via Portal, you can also try running the Az CLI and PowerShell commands mentioned in the document above.